# Prove the inequality for $3$ numbers

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Given $x,y,z$ are reals such that $0<x<y<z<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Prove that $$\frac{\pi}{2}+2\sin x\cos y+2\sin y\cos z>\sin 2x+\sin 2y+\sin 2z$$ Since the inequality is not symmetric and equality too doesn't hold, I don't have many ideas. I tried using some rearrangement inequality, but it doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: $0\lt x\lt y\lt z\lt \frac {\pi}2  \implies 0\lt \sin x\lt \sin y\lt \sin z\lt 1$. Does this helps a bit?

Comment: $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x \cos x$ seems like it could be of use.

Comment: And the most relevant fact about $\frac\pi2$ on the left-hand side is probably that it exceeds $\frac32$, which would be useful because $0\le p\le q\le\frac\pi2$ implies $\sin p\cos q\le \frac12$.

Comment: Hint:$0\lt x\lt y\lt z\lt \frac {\pi}2$, so, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are increasing and decreasing respectively of this order . Now, take the help of $Rearrangement$-$inequality$.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey are you sure rearrangement is enough? I think you get close with that but not to the finish line.

Comment: With an approch very similar to the proof of the Schur-Vornicu inequality it is possible to prove that the constant $\frac{\pi}{2}$ may be replaced with the smaller $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: For the OP: as a math entusiast, it would be a good thing to give some credit to the people who answered your questions by accepting their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our inequality is equivalent to:

$$f(x,y,z)=\sin(x)(\cos(x)-\cos(y))+\sin(y)(\cos(y)-\cos(z))+\sin(z)\cos(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{1}$$
but due to the concavity of the sine function, if we set $g(t)=\sin(t)\cos(t)$ we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}2\cdot f(x,y,z)&=&g(x)+g(z)+g(y-x)+g(z-y)\\&\leq&g(x)+g(z)+2\cdot g\left(\frac{z-x}{2}\right)\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
so it is enough to prove that if $0\leq x\leq z\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$$ h(x,z)=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\sin(z)\cos(z)+\sin(z-x)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\tag{3}$$
holds. It is easy to check that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}$ both vanish iff $\cos(x+z)\cos(x-z)=0$, i.e. $z=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$. So, in order to prove $(3)$ it is enough to check that if $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$,
$$ j(x) = \sin(2x)+\cos(2x)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\tag{4} $$
holds. That is trivial by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: moreover, the RHS of $(4)$ can be replaced with the smaller constant $\sqrt{2}$. So we have:

> If $0\leq x\leq y\leq z\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$,
>   $$\color{red}{\sqrt{2}}+2\sin x\cos y+2\sin y\cos z \geq \sin(2x)+\sin(2y)+\sin(2z).\tag{5}$$